# position cursor in init rebinding macro

Tags: emacs, lisp

I am trying to make a keyboard macro that prints a LaTeX macro and places the cursor inside it.
For example, I have the following placed in my .emacs file:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c v") "\\bibleverse{}()")
```

I would like to set the cursor inside the curly brackets

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c v") "\\bibleverse{<cursor position>}()")
```

How would I do this? Is there a macro for cursor position in emacs lisp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(defun latex-bibleverse-snippet ()
  (interactive)
  (insert "\\bibleverse{}()")
  (backward-char 3))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-c v") 'latex-bibleverse-snippet)
```

Maybe a quick and dirty answer. Or you can take a look at [YASnippet](https://github.com/capitaomorte/yasnippet), or [Predictive mode(provide **IntelliSense** features for some major modes (currently: LaTeX, Texinfo, HTML). )](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PredictiveMode) :-)

Comment: this totally works. quick and dirty is fine for now. Thank you for the links. I'll look into a solution in the future.